# Listview, Header overlaps the listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a Listview with a header, below it a sticky header and then a list.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

This is what it looks like when I scroll a bit down:

[image]

As you can see, the arrow overlaps the list. This is the effect I want.
I've tried to set a negative padding on the sticky header layout, but this didn't work.

Layout of sticky header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/root"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:paddingBottom="-10dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/view_dropshadow"
    android:paddingBottom="6dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_around_here"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/properties_around_location"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/back_to_top_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:text="Terug naar top"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_go_to_top" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-6dp"
    android:background="@drawable/indicator_arrow" />
```